# Consulta if dentro de un trigger

Tags: mysql

Si actualizo persona con un vacío que no inserte nada en Auditoria, pero si actualizo persona con un dato, nombre, etc., que si haga un `INSERT`. Tengo una tabla de reservas con horarios, cuando alguien reserva actualizo el campo persona asociado al horario, y eso dispara el `trigger` que deja el registro de quien registro, cuando, etc., pero a su vez tengo un evento que todos los días a las 00:00:00 `update` todos los campos personas a vacío para que al otro día se pueda volver a resolver, ese es el problema, el `update` de reserva esta ok, cuando se ejecuta el evento el `trigger` me toma los 24 updates vacíos y me inserta 24 datos vacíos en la tabla auditoria

Este es el código del `trigger` que tengo actualmente

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Pc_Auditoria 
AFTER UPDATE ON pcTotal
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO auditoria (pc, personaAnterior, horario, persona, fecha_mod)
VALUES (NEW.pc, OLD.persona, NEW.horario, NEW.persona, NOW());
DELIMITER ;
```

[image: Cuando hago una reserva]
[image: La tabla auditoria Ok]
[image: Tabla auditoria cuando se ejecute el evento]

Cuando hago una reserva:
El registro insertado ok en la auditoria:
Como queda la auditoria cuando se ejecuta el evento:

Comment: ¿Has intentado agregar la sentencia `IF` antes del `INSERT` antes de publicar la pregunta? ¿Con qué errores o problemas te has topado? O es que solo esperas que alguien en el sitio (de muy buena fe) haga el trabajo por ti? Por favor considera que debes mostrar tu propio esfuerzo para intentar resolver el problema, no solo colocar acá tu trabajo y esperar que alguien acá lo atienda.

Comment: Buenos dias Luiggi, probe con beggin, con el if, me dio errores en el end if; en la linea 6 luego de '', luego no me dejaba seleccionar desde delimiter, basicamente estoy desde las 10 de la mañana con esto. El ultimo que intente fue este pero tampoco: DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Pc_Auditoria
BEFORE UPDATE ON pcTotal
FOR EACH ROW
IF new.coordinador !='' THEN
INSERT INTO auditoria (pc, coordinadorAnterior, horario, coordinador, fecha_mod)
VALUES (NEW.pc, OLD.coordinador, NEW.horario, NEW.coordinador, NOW());
END IF;
DELIMITER ;

Comment: Lo que intente tambien es que si son las 00:00:00 el trigger no se ejecute, asi no me inserta los 24 datos vacios en la tabla auditoria, pero no me salio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes intentar lo siguiente:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Pc_Auditoria AFTER UPDATE ON pcTotal
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF <tu condición aca> THEN BEGIN
        INSERT INTO auditoria (pc, personaAnterior, horario, persona, fecha_mod)
        VALUES (NEW.pc, OLD.persona, NEW.horario, NEW.persona, NOW());
    END; END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Donde `<tu condición aca>` satisfaga las validaciones que creas correspondientes. Según mencionas en tu pregunta si el campo es vacío entonces no debe actualizarse. Imagino que con vacío te refieres a `NULL`, así que la condición sería algo así:

```
IF NEW.persona IS NOT NULL THEN
```

De acuerdo a tus comentarios:

- El campo a revisar es `coordinador`.
- El trigger debe ser antes de actualizar `pcTotal`.

Con esto en mente, tu trigger quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Pc_Auditoria BEFORE UPDATE ON pcTotal
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF COALESCE(NEW.coordinador, '') != '' THEN BEGIN
        INSERT INTO auditoria (pc, personaAnterior, horario, persona, fecha_mod)
        VALUES (NEW.pc, OLD.persona, NEW.horario, NEW.persona, NOW());
    END; END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Nótese el uso de la función `COALESCE` para validar si el valor de `NEW.coordinador` es `NULL` que entonces devuelva una cadena vacía `''`.

Comment: Gracias por responder Luiggi, use el que pasaste y llego al mismo final que con todos los otros, me inserta campos vacíos al ejecutarse el evento que updatea a vacio todos los campos personas.

Comment: ¿Puedes indicar cuál es el campo que debes validar que no esté vacío? Eso no queda claro en tu pregunta.

Comment: El campo es Persona, cuando alguien reserva updateo a la persona segun el horario que eligió y todos los días a las 00:00:00 updateo todos los campos persona a vació para que al otro día puedan volver a reservar el horario que quieran

Comment: Ok, entonces mi siguiente pregunta sería: ¿cómo sabes si una persona está vacía? ¿Puedes editar tu pregunta y proveer un ejemplo de cómo lucen los datos luego que se actualizó la tabla y contiene a una "persona vacía"? De esta manera, yo actualizaré mi respuesta. Te recomiendo colocar el resultado de la ejecución de un query y con los nombres de las columnas. Si tienes problemas con el indentado, alguien (quizás yo) editará el texto para que sea más presentable.

Comment: LISTO!!!   DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Pc_Auditoria BEFORE UPDATE ON pcTotal
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF new.persona!= '' THEN BEGIN
        INSERT INTO auditoria1 (pc, personaAnterior, horario, persona, fecha_mod)
        VALUES (NEW.pc, OLD.persona, NEW.horario, NEW.persona, NOW());
    END; END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta en base a lo que indicas en tu último comentario. Si esta respuesta te ha ayudado, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/428/227)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!! Por fin me puedo ir del trabajo jaja. Que tengas un excelente día.

Comment: me podrian ayudar con un caso, quiero hacer una condicion si el campo ya esta añadido no vovler a añadirlo... en un if.. para un trigger.. estoy empezando a desarrollarme en trigger.. les agradeceria bastante...